# How to linearize $\log \left(p\right)=6,89745-\frac{B}{t+a}$

Tags: calculus

I need to apply the least square method to the function exposed, so I supposed it needs to be linearize first, but I don't know how. P (pressure) is a function of the temperature t and B and a,  two constants.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the model$$\log \left(p\right)=C-\frac{B}{t+A}$$ is simple, it is nonlinear and, by the end, you will need nonlinear regression which implies the need of reasonable parameters.

As you wrote, the idea is to try to linearize the model first to get easy estimates of $A
$ and $B$. So, rewrite the model as

$$\frac{t+A}B=\frac 1{C-\log(p)}=\alpha t+\beta$$ So, define $z_i=\frac 1{C-\log(p_i)}$, perform a linear regression to get $(\alpha ,\beta)$ from which you deduce $(A,B)$.

Now, you are ready for the nonlinear regression that you **must** perform.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to linearize it to apply least squares. If you have a sample of the form $(t_1, p_1) \cdots (t_n, p_n)$ you can define

$$
f(a, B) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left[\ln p_i - \left(6.89745 - \frac{B}{t_i - a} \right) \right]^2
$$

Finding the minimum of $f$ may require some numerical approach, but there are plenty of tools to do that

Answer (score 0):

This problem is the fitting of an hyperbolic function.

Since no criteria of fitting is specified in the wordind of the question it can be transformed to a simple linear regression fitting (wrt xy instead of wrt y) :

[image]

If a specific criteria of fitting was required wrt y for example LMSE or LMSRE or LMAE or other one would have to use nonlinear regression which is an iterative process starting from "guessed" values of the parameters. Then the values found above would be good initial values.